Can i buy laptop on emi i need it too much
I want to buy  a laptop to start learning graphics design  and start earning but graphics design  needs a powerful  laptop and that is expensive  which comes around 1 lakh rupees and I can't  afford  it directly, so can can I buy  it on emi.
